Beamer changing footline
I'd like to change footline in beamer presentation. Now I am using this code to change it:
\makeatother
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
    \leavevmode%
    \hbox{%
            {\small \hspace*{.15cm}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle\hspace*{11.1cm}
            (\insertframenumber{})\hspace*{1ex}}}%
    \vskip3pt%
}
\makeatletter

But in this way in all presentations the value of hspace between title and frame number depend on title lenght and when I change this hspace on hfill, it doesnt work.
How can I create a fixed distance of the presentation number from the right end of the slides?

Can you make your snippet into something we can compile to reproduce the problem? Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

\documentclass{beamer}

\title{text}
\setbeamerfont{title in head/foot}{size=\small}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
  \hspace*{.15cm}\usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
  \hfill(\insertframenumber)\hspace*{.15cm}\vskip3pt%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  abc
\end{frame}

\end{document}


